# Real time progress with the backend

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, angular6

I have an app working springboot as my backend and angular 6 as the front end. In my front end there is a button when it clicks, using rest calls it invoks a method in springboot. That method will start to work and one process will be start to execute. That process will be working in the terminal. What i want is, how to get the progress of that process in to my front end. As that process is running in the background, after clicking the button client wont have an idea whether the clicked event worked or not?

Comment: Think a spinner will do. What you can do is do the call to the backend start the spinner. When it return back to the client it's done and the spinner dissapear.

Comment: @Swoox your comment is out of scope. the asker wants to know the progress of execution in the backend in real time.

Answer (score -1):

If your backend is able to determine the progress of your operation, you could implement [Progress Events](https://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/) and display the progress to the user (e.g., using a progress bar). Otherwise a loading indicator (e.g., a spinner) is a common tool to display some sort of background activity.

As this is not necessarily related to a specific technology, I'd recommend to take a look at some UX threads discussing loading indicators:

- [How should long loading times be handled?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/80850/how-should-long-loading-times-be-handled?rq=1)
- [Does a loading animation on a websites initial load improve usability?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72833/does-a-loading-animation-on-a-websites-initial-load-improve-usability)